# cisco ASA 5505 l2tp vpn

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, l2tp

I have a problem with cisco asa 5505 vpn configuration. I set l2tp for windows clients. I can connect to vpn but:

1. when i have "use default gateway on remote network" on NIC enabled i have access to all resources in network but i don't have internet access (can't open websites etc).
2. when i have "use default gateway on remote network" on NIC disabled i dont have access to resources in network but i have internet access.

In my config file there is a little mess i tried to use ASDM and tried to configure Cisco Anyconnect but those lines in config aren't important and don't work. My VPN subnet is 192.168.20.0 and  I need only l2tp for windows. If someone wants to help here is my config:

```
 Saved
:
ASA Version 9.1(2) 
!
hostname ciscoasa
enable password xxx encrypted
names
ip local pool poolVPN 192.168.20.10-192.168.20.30 mask 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.0.254 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address xxx.xxx.xxx.26 255.255.255.248 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 nameif dmz
 security-level 50
 ip address 192.168.100.254 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/5
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface Management0/0
 management-only
 nameif management
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 
!
ftp mode passive
object network branch1
 subnet 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
object network branch2
 subnet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
object network branch3
 subnet 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0
object network branch4
 subnet 192.168.4.0 255.255.255.0
object network branch5
 subnet 192.168.5.0 255.255.255.0
object network central
 subnet 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
object network dmz-subnet
 subnet 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0
object network camera-monitoring-ip
 host xxx.xxx.xxx.27
object network cameras
 host 192.168.100.1
object network NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.20.0_27
 subnet 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.224
access-list oudside_acl extended permit tcp any object cameras eq www 
access-list outside_acl extended permit tcp any object cameras eq www 
access-list dmz_int extended permit tcp host 192.168.100.1 eq www any 
access-list DefaultRAGroup_splitTunnelAcl standard permit 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list DefaultRAGroup_splitTunnelAcl standard permit 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.224 
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging asdm informational
mtu management 1500
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
mtu dmz 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
nat (inside,outside) source static any any destination static NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.20.0_27 NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.20.0_27 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (inside,outside) source static NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.20.0_27 NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.20.0_27 destination static NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.20.0_27 NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.20.0_27 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
!
object network branch1
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
object network branch2
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
object network branch3
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
object network branch4
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
object network branch5
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
object network central
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
object network dmz-subnet
 nat (dmz,outside) dynamic interface
object network cameras
 nat (dmz,outside) static cameras-monitoring-ip service tcp www www 
access-group outside_acl in interface outside
access-group dmz_int in interface dmz
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 xxx.xxx.xxx.25 1
route inside 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.170 1
route inside 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.170 1
route inside 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.170 1
route inside 192.168.4.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.170 1
route inside 192.168.5.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.170 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL 
http server enable
http 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 management
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart warmstart
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES
 protocol esp encryption des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES
 protocol esp encryption aes
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES192
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-192-SHA ESP-AES-256-SHA ESP-3DES-SHA ESP-DES-SHA ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS
crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256 AES192 AES 3DES DES
crypto map outside_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP
crypto map outside_map interface outside
crypto ca trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint0
 enrollment self
 subject-name CN=ciscoasa
 keypair xxxxx
 crl configure
crypto ca trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint1
 enrollment terminal
 subject-name CN=ciscoasa  
 crl configure
crypto ca trustpool policy
crypto ca certificate chain ASDM_TrustPoint0
 certificate 9gfdrfss
    fdfasfd vczvc
  quit
crypto ikev2 policy 1
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 10
 encryption aes-192
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 20
 encryption aes
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 30
 encryption 3des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 40
 encryption des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 enable outside client-services port 443
crypto ikev2 remote-access trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint0
crypto ikev1 enable outside
crypto ikev1 policy 10
 authentication crack
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 20
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 30
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 40
 authentication crack
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 50
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 60
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 70
 authentication crack
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 80
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 90
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 100
 authentication crack
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 110
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 120
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 130
 authentication crack
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 140
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 150
 authentication pre-share
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
telnet timeout 5
ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 inside
ssh timeout 5
ssh version 2
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 0
dhcpd address 192.168.1.2-192.168.1.254 management
dhcpd enable management
!
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
webvpn
 enable outside
 anyconnect image disk0:/anyconnect-win-2.5.2014-k9.pkg 1
 anyconnect profiles VPNanyconnect_client_profile disk0:/VPNanyconnect_client_profile.xml
 anyconnect enable
 tunnel-group-list enable
group-policy DefaultRAGroup internal
group-policy DefaultRAGroup attributes
 wins-server value 192.168.0.201
 dns-server value 192.168.0.201 xxx.xxx.xxx.244
 vpn-tunnel-protocol l2tp-ipsec 
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value DefaultRAGroup_splitTunnelAcl
 default-domain value xxxxx
group-policy DefaultRAGroup_1 internal
group-policy DefaultRAGroup_1 attributes
 wins-server value 192.168.0.201
 dns-server value 192.168.0.201 xxx.xxx.xxx.244
 vpn-tunnel-protocol l2tp-ipsec 
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value DefaultRAGroup_splitTunnelAcl
 default-domain value xxxx.local
group-policy GroupPolicy_VPNanyconnect internal
group-policy GroupPolicy_VPNanyconnect attributes
 wins-server value 192.168.0.201
 dns-server value 192.168.0.201 xxx.xxx.xxx.244
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev2 
 default-domain value xxx.local
 webvpn


!
class-map icmp-class
 match default-inspection-traffic
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map icmp_policy
 class icmp-class
  inspect icmp 
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect ip-options 
!
service-policy global_policy global
service-policy icmp_policy interface outside
prompt hostname context 
no call-home reporting anonymous
Cryptochecksum:xxx68c1xxx5dbef0baxxxf2378e540
: end
no asdm history enable
```

---

Thanks for reply.

```
access-list DefaultRAGroup_splitTunnelAcl standard permit 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0  group-policy
DefaultRAGroup internal group-policy 
DefaultRAGroup attributes  wins-server value 192.168.0.201  
dns-server value 192.168.0.201 xxx.xxx.xxx.244  
vpn-tunnel-protocol l2tp-ipsec   
split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified  
split-tunnel-network-list value DefaultRAGroup_splitTunnelAcl  
default-domain value xxxxx
```

yeah i did split tunneling before as shown in tutorial but it doesn't work. I added ACL and ACE, restarted router. No idea what's wrong here...

Comment: Take case 1, add a NAT (outside, outside) source dynamic ANYCONNECT-VPN. Should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't configure the [Split Tunnel](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/70917-asa-split-tunnel-vpn-client.html).

Basically, when you enable `use default gateway on remote network` as soon as you connect to the VPN, your default gateway becomes the VPN endpoint and all traffic transit towards that gateway.

When it's not enabled you are simply missing the routes to reach whatever is beyond the VPN tunnel and still use your own default gateway for everything else.